# Include resources into an EXE file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm curently working on a software in C++ using MFC with VS2012. 
There is a lot of pictures in it. All the pictures are located in a folder "pictures" and the programme loads them when it is launch.

So the problem is when I want to create a release of it I have to include the folder "pictures" with it which is ridiculous. The programme is a bit professional and giving a folder with all the pictures in it is not pro.

So I'd like to load all the pictures in ressources of my programme. Then all the pictures will be in the Exe file.

Also I need to change the loading of a picture (I mean using several pictures for a single slot in a window)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380599%28VS.85%29.aspx

This may be of help.

Comment: Why do you think it's "not pro" to include a folder with all the pictures in your program? If you take a look at, for instance, the Visual Studio installation (I'm using VS2010 but it should be similar for 2012), you'll see that gifs and bitmaps for the UI are simply included in the installation folder. Most commercial apps that I know and use do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the images as resources, and then you can load them:

```
CBitmap::LoadBitmap(LPCTSTR lpszResourceName)
CBitmap::LoadBitmap(UINT nIDResource)
```

will load an image from a BITMAP resource.

If your images are not BITMAPs, it would be easier to create them as such. Otherwise, you can see [this Code Project page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI) for loading JPG and PNG.